# Proper way to remove a child fragment from a FrameLayout with multiple sources

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a FrameLayout which can be filled with different fragments based upon the user's choice on a RadioGroup. However, I am quite certain that the method I am using to remove such fragments is far from ideal and if possible, I would like some insights on how to make this properly.

How I am removing the fragments right now:

```java
(...)
//Inside the body of the OnViewCreated
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();

//RadioGroup listener to show a fragment based on the user's choice
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
            //getCheckedRadio is only a method I created to get the index of the option chosen by the user
            int index = getCheckedRadio(group);
            switch (index) {
                case 1:
                    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.child_fragment, new FragmentA()).commit();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.child_fragment, new FragmentB()).commit();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.child_fragment, new FragmentC()).commit();
                    break;
                default:
                    removeFragments();
                    break;
            }
(...)

//Method I use to remove the fragments
public void removeFragments() {
        try {
            FragmentA fragA = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.child_fragment);
            if (fragA != null)
                manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragA).commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                FragmentB fragB = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.child_fragment);
                if (fragB != null)
                manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragB).commit();
            } catch (Exception f) {
                try {
                    FragmentC fragC = (FragmentC) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.child_fragment);
                    if (fragC != null)
                        manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragC).commit();
                } catch (Exception g) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I know that this method is far from perfect because, should I call it at any point outside of `radioGroup.SetOnCheckedChangeListener`, it won't remove the fragment being exposed at the time. So my question is: Which is the correct way to remove a fragment from a FrameLayout that can hold different types of Fragments? And why my `removeFragments()` method works when used on this listener but not when called at other points in the code?

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the correct way to remove a fragment from a FrameLayout that can hold different types of Fragments?

**First**

No need to be bothered by what types of fragments that can be hosted by a `FrameLayout` placeholder; at the end of the day they are all Fragments (i.e. subclasses of the `Fragment` class).

**Second**

Not sure if there is a misconception of the fragment transaction concept; as the name of the method `removeFragments()` implies to remove multiple fragment(s) from a single placeholder at a time; and the logic of the method applies that to `FragmentA, B, & C` (i.e. there is a thought that more than one fragment can exist at a time); and this is not right; as at a time, a single placeholder/container can hold one and only one fragment.

This is something different than the back stack which can have multiple instances of the fragments according to the user navigation.

So, the `removeFragments()` actually need to be `removeFragment()` where only one fragment need to be removed at a time.

I guess that you thought that replacing a fragment keeps the old one in the placeholder, [as per documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#add-remove):

> Calling replace() is equivalent to calling remove() with a fragment in a container and adding a new fragment to that same container.

**Third**

There is no need to wrap the `remove(fragment)` into a try catch block; this method doesn't through any exception at all, so you will never get into the catch block; even if the fragment isn't the current fragment of the container, then it silently discard it.

So, the logic in `removeFragments()` can be simplified to:

```
public void removeFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.child_fragment);
    if (fragment != null)
        manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}
```

> should I call it at any point outside of radioGroup.SetOnCheckedChangeListener

This depends on the logic/event you want to use to remove the fragment.

Comment: At first, I want to thank you for your reply! It really helped me to clear my ```removeFragments()``` method. I thought I had to specify each Fragment type to remove it instead of using a more generic method.

Just to correct you, though, that method GOES through an exception if I have a Fragment B filling that FrameLayout and I try to cast it into a variable like a Fragment A. But using your method, I'll just avoid all this unecessary code.

I still am having trouble about removing the fragments when calling the method at other points in the code, I'll make a more through check about it.